# Hide advanced custom fields items behind a checkbox

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I have several advanced custom field items for different tasks on a post. I am looking for a way to group together fields for every separate task and hide them behind a checkbox so the user does not get confused between different fields.

Answer (score 0):

Add a checkbox, and then make your fields conditional based on whether the checkbox is checked. This is built-in ACF functionality. When you select "conditional" in ACF, it will show a dropdown for you to set when the field should be visible or not.